# Mongoose save method test false pass with jest

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, chai

I try to test a Mongoose model with Jest. The model contains a property named `email` that must contain unique value. This is the test I try to run:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bluebird from 'bluebird'

import Author from '../Author' // this is the model I try to test

mongoose.Promise = bluebird
describe('email key', () => {
  beforeAll((done) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test')

    let db = mongoose.connection

    db.on('error', (err) => {
      done.fail(err)
    })

    db.once('open', () => {
      done()
    })
  })

  test('duplicate email', () => {
    const a = new Author({
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      name: 'some',
      nickname: 'oether',
      role: 'admin'
    })

    const b = new Author({
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      name: 'a',
      nickname: 'a',
      role: 'admin'
    })

    a.save()
      .then((doc) => console.log(doc))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))

    b.save() // should throw error on test
      .then((doc) => console.log(doc))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  })

  afterAll((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase().then(() => {
      mongoose.connection.close()
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Here is the schema file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  }
})

const authorModel = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)
export default authorModel
```

### What do I expect?

I expect to get an error in the console when execute the `save()` method on `b`, something like `email field should contain unique values`.

### What do I get?

The console shows that the test pass successfully (`✓ duplicate email (2ms)`). Moreover the test is being hanged and won't terminate util I press `ctrl+c` to manually terminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.save and b.save, are being executed concurrently. I'm not sure why the test is hanging, but try:

```
a.save()
 .then.(() => b.save())
 .then(console.log) 
 .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. But what I see now is that the test one time pass and the next fails, and the again pass and then again fails. Is it something with how I handle the connection?

Comment: I would ask another question about that.  But you are definitely setting up your tests in an unusual way.  Why do your assertions in beforeAll on the datbase events?  It is more typical to do this in the test itself.  There are many, many examples for testing mongoose in the internet. Follow one of those.